# javascript преобразовать цифры в дату

Tags: javascript

как преобразовать такие циферки: 1515237073 в конкретную дату?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотря что эти цифры означают. Если это количество миллисекунд, прошедшее с 1 января 1970 года (традиционная условная дата отсчёта для компьютерных дат), тогда можно так:

```js
const date = new Date(1515237073);

console.log(date.toLocaleString());
```

Если это [Unix-время](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F), тогда нужно сначала умножить на `1000`:

```js
const date = new Date(1515237073 * 1000);

console.log(date.toLocaleString());
```

См. подробнее в [`Date()` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date).